# how to subclass multiprocessing.JoinableQueue

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to subclass `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` so I can keep track of jobs that were skipped instead of completed. I am using a JoinableQueue to pass jobs to a set of `multiprocessing.Process`'s and I have a `threading.Thread` populating the queue. Here is my implementation attempt:

```
import multiprocessing

class InputJobQueue(multiprocessing.JoinableQueue):

    def __init__(self, max_size):
        super(InputJobQueue, self).__init__(0)
        self._max_size = max_size
        self._skipped_job_count = 0

    def isFull(self):
        return self.qsize() >= self._max_size

    def taskSkipped(self):
        self._skipped_job_count += 1
        self.task_done()
```

However, I run into this issue documented [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue19895):

```
class InputJobQueue(multiprocessing.JoinableQueue):
TypeError
:
Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Looking at the code in `multiprocessing` I see that the actual class is in `multiprocessing.queues`. So I try to extend that class:

```
import multiprocessing.queues

class InputJobQueue(multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue):

    def __init__(self, max_size):
        super(InputJobQueue, self).__init__(0)
        self._max_size = max_size
        self._skipped_job_count = 0

    def isFull(self):
        return self.qsize() >= self._max_size

    def taskSkipped(self):
        self._skipped_job_count += 1
        self.task_done()
```

But I get inconsistent results: sometimes my custom attributes exist, other times they don't. E.g. the following error is reported in one of my worker Processes:

```
AttributeError: 'InputJobQueue' object has no attribute '_max_size'
```

What am I missing to subclass `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`?

Comment: By the way, IIRC, one of the critical bugs that was fixed in 3.2+ `multiprocessing` was that processes that inherit queues don't always work properly. I think there's a backport of the 3.2 (or later?) `multiprocessing` on PyPI that fixes that; you might want to install that (and look at the source to the wrapper function to see how to get and pass a context object to the actual queue object). But I don't think that's your problem here.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the backport has been superseded by [`billiard`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/billiard/), so use that instead of searching for the backport.

Answer (score 3):

With `multiprocessing`, the way objects like `JoinableQueue` are magically shared between processes is by explicitly sharing the core sync objects, and pickling the "wrapper" stuff to pass over a pipe.

If you understand how pickling works, you can look at the source to [`JoinableQueue`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#l273) and see that it's using `__getstate__`/`__setstate__`. So, you just need to override those to add your own attributes. Something like this:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return super(InputJobQueue, self).__getstate__() + (self._max_size,)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    super(InputJobQueue, self).__setstate__(state[:-1])
    self._max_size = state[-1]
```

I'm not promising this will actually *work*, since clearly these classes were not designed to be subclassed (the proposed fix for the bug you referenced is to document that the classes can't be subclassed and find a way to make the error messages nicer…). But it should get you past the particular problem you're having here.

Comment: That bug report is just saying that it should be clearer that the `JoinableQueue` in the top-level `multiprocessing` module is a function, not a class, and that the real class is in `multiprocessing.queues`. Subclassing the actual `Queue` objects works fine, as long as you handle pickling/unpickling properly (which your answer covers).

Comment: @dano: Subclassing a documented type that's meant to be subclassed wouldn't require knowledge of the internals of its implementation. There's no way to know that `JoinableQueue` happens to use the `__setstate__` mechanism for pickling without reading the source, and no reason to expect that in Python 3.5 it won't change.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that `JoinableQueue` is *designed* to be subclassed; the way `Queue` implements `__getstate__` makes it clear that it isn't (though `JoinableQueue` is a subclass of `Queue`). I was just saying that this statement you made about the bug report isn't quite accurate: *"the proposed fix for the bug you referenced is to document that the classes can't be subclassed"*. At least not based on anything actually written in the bug report. The report just suggests documenting that you need to `import multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue` for subclassing to work.

Comment: And fwiw I agree that delegating is the better choice. I've been working on integrating `multiprocessing` classes with `asyncio`, and properly sub-classing all those objects is proving to be more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to subclass a type that isn't meant to be subclassed. This requires you to depend on the internals of its implementation in two different ways (one of which is arguably a bug in the stdlib, but the other isn't). And this isn't necessary.

If the actual type is hidden under the covers, no code can actual expect you to be a formal subtype; as long as you duck-type as a queue, you're fine. Which you can do by delegating to a member:

```
class InputJobQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self._jq = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue(0)
        self._max_size = max_size
        self._skipped_job_count = 0
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._jq, name)
    # your overrides/new methods
```

(It would probably be cleaner to explicitly delegate only the documented methods of `JoinableQueue` than to `__getattr__`-delegate everything, but in the interests of brevity, I did the shorter version.)

It doesn't matter whether that constructor is a function or a class, because the only thing you're doing is calling it. It doesn't matter how the actual type is pickled, because a class is only responsible for identifying its members, not knowing how to pickle them. All of your problems go away.